# Deriving p-value from Fisher's z'

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value

I am looking to derive a p-value to complete a hypothesis on the correlation between two independent variables. This is the data I have so far

Pearson's r = 0.55
Fisher’s z' = 0.618

How do I calculate the p-value for z'?

Edit (1):
my x and y data being compared in the correlation are not normal distributions. So, in order to get a more accurate p-value and confidence interval, I transformed Pearson's r to z'. I know how to calculate the confidence interval, but i'm not sure how to calculate the p-value for z'.

Edit(2):
My data has 215 observations for both x and y. Is a t-test sufficient to get the p-value?

Comment: What is the hypothesis?  That the correlation is zero or that it is a specific correlation?

Comment: @whuber They hypothesis is that the correlation is 0